# Blogger.com: Can I read <data:post.title /> that containing special characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, blogger

I assume the data of `<data:post.title/>` is:

> This is "post title' that contain special characters

## How do I read the data with javascript without put it into HTML document first. ?

Usually, the data taken by put it into HTML document first:

### HTML

```
<div id="post-title-wrapper">
<data:post.title/>
</div>
```

### JS:

```
var post_title = document.getElementById("post-title-wrapper").innerHTML; // This work
```

However, I just want to read this data without put it into html document first:

### JS ONLY:

```
     var post_title = "<data:post.title/>";

    // not work, this is because there are special characters in the data.
    // the script will be interrupted:
    // var post_title = "This is "post title' that contain special characters";
```

### What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

With ES2015 [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you can use back-tick ``(grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes.

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them.

```
var post_title = `<data:post.title/>`;
```

Comment: Here, i do not know what special caracters that may contain in the data. so, it can be ",  ' ,  `, or others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, when I try to retrieve data that also contains back-tick character, it does not work ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Wrap escaped double quotes (`&#34;`) or single quote (`&#39;`) around `<data:post.title/>`

```
var post_title = &#34;<data:post.title/>&#34;;
```

or

```
var post_title = &#39;<data:post.title/>&#39;;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var post_title = &#39;<data:post.title.escaped/>&#39;;
```

To unescape:

```
post_title = $('<textarea/>').html(post_title).text();
```

Hope this helps